# SyntaxError: invalid or unexpected token, req.body.10P

Tags: express

I am trying to request the body of a column in my mySQL query and keep getting an invalid or unexpected token. I believe this has to do with the fact that my column name starts with a number, but I've tried to surround it with "" and '' and `` and get unexpected string, string, and template string, respectively. Thank you for any help!

mySQL Query

```
'INSERT INTO mgma2019tcc ( \
        owner, \
        pk_mgma2019tcc, \
        specialty, \
        groupCount, \
        indCount, \
        mean, \
        stdDev, \
        10P, 11P, 12P, 13P, 14P, \
        15P, 16P, 17P, 18P, 19P, \
        ... \
      ) VALUES ( \
        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, \
...
      )'
```

Here are my requests.

```
[ // extract the body portion of the incoming request stream and expose it on req.body
         owner,
         req.body.pk_mgma2019tcc,
         req.body.specialty,
         req.body.groupCount,
         req.body.indCount,
         req.body.mean,
         req.body.stdDev,
         req.body.10P, req.body.11P, req.body.12P, req.body.13P, req.body.14P,
         req.body.15P, req.body.16P, req.body.17P, ...
       ]
```

This is the error message I keep getting.

[syntaxerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPYKM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that variable names and property names can't start with a number.

If you're interested you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables#An_aside_on_variable_naming_rules

However, you could access the variables using bracket notation like so:

```
[ // extract the body portion of the incoming request stream and expose it on req.body
         owner,
         req.body.pk_mgma2019tcc,
         req.body.specialty,
         req.body.groupCount,
         req.body.indCount,
         req.body.mean,
         req.body.stdDev,
         req.body['10P'], req.body['11P'], req.body['12P'], req.body['13P'], req.body['14P'],
         req.body['15P'], req.body['16P'], req.body['17P'], ...
       ]
```

Comment: Can I change this to P10, P11, P12...?

Answer (score 0):

Variable names and object properties can't start with a number.
However, if you still insist on sending the request keys starting with a number, you can use square bracket notation to get the value of those properties.
Therefore, you need to type:

```
req.body['10P'],
req.body['11P'],
req.body['12P'],
req.body['13P'],
req.body['14P'],
req.body['15P'],
req.body['16P'],
req.body['17P']
```

Notice the differences that using square brackets access the values similar to accessing by index from an array, but instead of the index, we use the  **String** of properties name. This also works when your object properties also includes whitespaces such as:

```
req.body['Group Count']
```